# PHP/jQuery form scripts sending duplicate emails?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email

I've tried to fix this problem, or find a similar problem, but I'm still scratching my head over this one.

I have an HTML form that I'm validating with a jQuery function, then passing it to a PHP script for mailing. The problem I'm having is once the functions run, there's a duplicate mail being sent, but the second one is blank, none of the data values are passed.

**The jQuery:**

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var quit = false;

    if(validateName()){
        name = validateName();
        $("label#name_error").fadeOut(0);
        $("label#name_error2").fadeOut(0);
    } else if (validateInput('name')){
        $("label#name_error").fadeOut(0);
        $("label#name_error2").fadeIn(250);
        quit = true;
    } else {
        $("label#name_error").fadeIn(250);
        $("label#name_error2").fadeOut(0);
        quit = true;
    }

    // several more validation checks for the other fields follow.

    if(quit){
        return false;
    }

    var dataString = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email; //and other fields inserted here

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/MailHandler.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            $('.error').fadeOut(0);
            $('#contact-form').clearForm();
            $('#contact').html("<div class='download-box'><h2>Thanks for contacting us!</h2><p>Someone will be in touch shortly!</p></div>").fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1500); 
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Which then sends to the **PHP** (MailHandler.php):

```
<?php
    $to = "email@email.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST["email"];
    $subject = "Testing the form " . $_REQUEST["name"];
    $headers = "From: " . $_REQUEST["email"] . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $_REQUEST["email"];

    $messageBody = "";  
    $messageBody .= $_REQUEST["name"] . "\n";
    $messageBody .= $_REQUEST["email"] . "\n";
    //and the other fields added similarly.

    if (mail($to, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        echo ("Mail Sent");
    } else {
        echo ("Mail Failed");
    }

?>
```

Once this runs, everything seems to process correctly, I get the success message and the email with all the correct data arrives.

A few minutes later a second email arrives, but with none of the data from the form. All the headers and data values are blank.

I've looked over the code, and I can't figure out where the second message is coming from. Does anyone see something I missed?? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: sidenote, you should sanitize those vars

Answer (score 1):

It appears the form is being submitted twice. Once by the form post, then once by the AJAX call. You might want to stick with the ajax call and not use a form tag, then also use a button other than a `submit` button to invoke the ajax call.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify. `#submit` is a link tag, not the form `<input type=submit>` button.

Answer (score 0):

In your MailHandler, you should check to see if the variables you need, aren't empty, before sending an e-mail.

If the vars are empty (http://php.net/empty) then you shouldn't send the mail. It is possible that an antivirus (such as Trend Micro) check the page to make sure there aren't any viruses on it.

Comment: I added a check to make sure $messageBody wasn't empty before running the mail function, but I'm still receiving empty emails.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that your php script is somehow called twice. Check this using firebird. If you use submit button type, you should disable its default functionality like this:

   `$('#submit').click(function(event) {

           event.preventDefault();

           // rest of your code

   });`
2. Don't use `$_REQUEST`, use `$_POST` instead.
3. Check if your `$_POST` variables are not empty before sending the email.

Comment: After some poking around, I agree, `$_POST` seems to be a better usage, so I switched those out. I'm not, however, using a submit button to process the form, it's a link tag. And did you mean Firebug as opposed to Firebird? Through Firebug, all the variables show up and only seem to call the script once, but I'm still getting the blank, duplicate emails. Go figure, still stumped on this one.

Comment: Even if you use the link you still need to call event.preventDefault(). Yes I meant Firebug - check out the network tab and see how many requests are made.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have more luck if you use the jquery .submit method rather just a click event,  shown here : http://api.jquery.com/submit/

So in the case of your code:

```
//where #target is your form ID
$('#target').submit(function() {
  //your code
  return false;
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
 $('#target').submit();
});
```

I think that will make it send the email once.

Comment: I gave it a go, but it still sends out the duplicate, blank emails.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something happening server-side, rather than my code. I moved the code to a different server and experienced no problem whatsoever.